# How to set focus to browser window using WatiN

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer, watin

I'm trying open new IE window with WatiN from WPF application. I want to focus on the IE window.
When I start project in debug mode it works correctly. But when I start without debugging new browser window not focused. Have any ideas?

Code for opening browser:

```
using (var browser = new IE(someAddress))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the C# code used to open the browser?

Comment: Ok. What other C# statements are you using to affect the browser's behavior?

Comment: Wait, I think I know what you are looking for. I'll post an answer. I've also done some searching and couldn't turn up any related SO questions either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this solution a while back by looking through the methods brought up by Visual Studio's Intellisense for the `IE` class.

```
using (var browser = new IE(someAddress))
{
    browser.BringToFront();

    // ... Your other code
}
```

The `IE#BringToFront()` method essentially sets focus to the window. Another common task is maximizing the window as well:

```
using (var browser = new IE(someAddress))
{
    // using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods;
    browser.ShowWindow(WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
    browser.BringToFront();

    // ... Your other code
}
```